# why _vti_bin/shtml.exe is accessible in default AWS setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS and I got a Spring microservice project that serve in AWS. I have Jboss7 running in AWS-EC2 instances and having setup AWS-ELB for load balancing.

I encounter an issue to remove microsoftsharepointteamservices version number in response header from a URL, for example www.domainName.com/_vti_bin/shtml.exe.

[image]

However, i have not idea why microsoft share point service come into picture as I do not install any web server or apache httpd in AWS.

**Why shtml.exe is accessible in default AWS setup? Or is it the other issue that related to ISS?**

Please kindly advice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause for this issue. This is due to we have setup Liferay CMS system in our AWS. And Microsoft Share Point service team service is bundle together with Liferay by default to support for Content Search module.